# Repeating the result of a user input

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I'm currently using the following VBA code to prompt the user to enter how many people will be needed for processing a spreadsheet.

```
Dim N As Long
    N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)
        If N > Rows.Count Then
            N = Rows.Count
        End If

        For i = 1 To N
            Cells(i + 1, 19) = i
        Next i
```

It accomplishes what I initially need as shown in the image but I want to repeat the count until the end of the document based on what data is left in column A. So the count should start at 1 in cell S20.

Any thoughts?

[Screenshot of initial Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQvLD.png)

Comment: Are you just wanting to fill in the next `N` rows each time, or do you want to repeat the numbers `1,2,3,...,N` as many times as necessary to get to the end of column A?

Comment: Hi, I want repeating numbers based on the users entry to run down Column S until there is no data in Column A.  i know a loop is involved but i can't figure it out.

Comment: If you're asking the users to enter a number then it seems that your code is working as designed.  If you want your code to update column S with numbers 1,2,3,...N until column A is null, then that's different and why ask the users how many people are needed.

Comment: Overall i can have about 50 to 500 rows of information that will need to be divided up among employees to review. The amount of employees may differ which is why I wanted the prompt. Based on the user's answer, I wanted to enter 1-N in a column. But i need this to repeat the sequence for every N rows. We can then filter the sheet to show only 1's, 2's or 3's so that the each employee who is assigned a number only reviews what is given to them.

Comment: LOL - I have to laugh at the test for `N` being greater than `Rows.Count` - there's not many companies with more than 1,048,576 employees! (But it is always good to build safe code! :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just loop across all the rows, but write out the (slightly adjusted) row number modulo N

```
Dim N As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=1)

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Cells(i, 19).Value = ((i - 2) Mod N) + 1
Next i
```